# C# - Best way to convert Month names to their month number

Tags: c#, date, date-conversion

Is there a function in C# that can already change a Month name to it's corresponding month number?  If not, should I make a method (like using 'Switch" or some loop function) that makes this possible?

I'm asking because I would like to have clean code and not make a huge mess in my code.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(monthName, "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
Convert.ToDateTime(monthName + " 01, 1900").Month;
```

or

```
Array.IndexOf(DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames,
              monthName.ToLower(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)) + 1;
```

and also

```
Array.FindIndex(DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames, 
                m => m.Equals(monthName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) + 1;
```